# Changing A JS Var With A Html Drop Down Menu

Tags: html, dropdown

Hi I Am Trying To Make A Dropdown Menu Where You Can Click On One Of The List Items To Purchase It (It’s For A Game) Basically So It Changes A JS Var Which If Changed Will Buy The Item And Remove An Amount Of Currency.(I Have No Idea How To Do The Html, But I Can Do The Vars In Javascript)

HTML

```
    <div class="dropdown">
  <button class="dropbtn">Shop</button>
  <div class="dropdown-content">
    <option >Glasses 10$</option>
    <option >Hat 15$</option>
    <option >Gold Chain 100$</option>
```

Answer (score -1):

I changed a bit your code. Is that what you asked ?
Each time an option is clicked, its removed from the html and its value is cumulated into a variable (price). 
Price var contains the sum of each clicked and removed option values.

```
<div class="dropdown">
  <button class="dropbtn">Shop</button>
  <div class="dropdown-content">
    <option value="10" >Glasses 10$</option>
    <option value="15">Hat 15$</option>
    <option value="100">Gold Chain 100$</option>
  </div>
    <div id="price">price</div>

<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.0.min.js"></script>
<script>
var price = 0;
$('.dropdown-content option').bind('click',function(e){
    //total price
    price += parseInt($(this).attr('value'));

    // remove selected item
    $(this).remove();

    //print total price
    $('#price').text(price);
});
</script>
```

Comment: Great formating, try adding some explanation of why you did what you did

Comment: The Option And Value Seem To Break The Dropdown Menu.